# Trying to find the next prime number

Tags: python

MyFunctions file file -

```
def factList(p,n1):
    counter = 1
    while counter <= n1:
        if n1 % counter == 0:
            p.append(counter)
        counter = counter + 1    



def isPrime(lst1,nbr):
    factList(lst1, nbr)
    if len(lst1) == 2:
        return True
    else:
        return False





def nextPrime(nbr1):
    cnt1 = 1
    while cnt1 == 1:
        nbr1 == nbr1 + 1
        if isPrime(lst2,nbr1):
            cnt1 = 0
```

Filetester file -

```
nbr1 = 13 
nextPrime(nbr1)
print nbr1
```

My isPrime function already works I'm tring to use my isPrime function for my nextPrime function, when I run this I get 
">>> 
13

> > > " (when using 13)

">>> " (When using 14)

I am supposed to get 17 not 13. And if I change it to a composite number in function tester it gets back in a infinite loop. Please only use simple functions (the ones I have used in my code).

Comment: `=` (assignment) != `==` (equality check)

Comment: We can't see what `factList` is doing.  Is it supposed to be modifying lst1?  Does it have a return value?  Perhaps the line should be `lst1 = factList(nbr)`

Comment: As I say I don't know python but it looks suspect to me that you are calling next prime with only 1 argument when it looks like it should be called with 2

Comment: Could you provide the factList function? (I assume returns a list of factors of nbr1 into lst1)

Comment: There's a lot wrong with this code.

Comment: Everything works but the nextPrime function?

Comment: No it doesn't, and you have side effects.

Comment: it does I have checked every function. and it works perfectly but the nextPrime.

Comment: Okay so where is lst2 coming from in nextPrime? do you not have to set it to an empty list at least?

Comment: To make code clearer in nextPrime I would use a boolean variable called found prime rather than cnt1

Comment: `cnt1` is not a necessary variable at all though.

Answer (score 2):

This is NOT the right way to do this, but this is the closest adaptation of your code that I could do:

```
def list_factors_pythonic(number):
    """For a given number, return a list of factors."""
    factors = []
    for x in range(1, number + 1):
        if number % x == 0:
            factors.append(x)
    return factors

def list_factors(number):
    """Alternate list_factors implementation."""
    factors = []
    counter = 1
    while counter <= number:
        if number % counter == 0:
            factors.append(counter)
    return factors  

def is_prime(number):
    """Return true if the number is a prime, else false."""
    return len(list_factors(number)) == 2

def next_prime(number):
    """Return the next prime."""
    next_number = number + 1
    while not is_prime(next_number):
        next_number += 1
    return next_number
```

Comment: list factors already works for me so I don't need to edit it.

Comment: You should not pass a mutable as an argument.  It's very bad practice.  If you run the function more than once, it will continue appending to the list.

Comment: Could you please use it? Since I can't use for and in? (because this is for school).

Answer (score 1):

This would be helpful:

```
def nextPrime(number):
    for i in range(2,number):
        if number%i == 0:
            return False
        sqr=i*i
        if sqr>number:
           break
    return True

number = int(input("Enter the num: ")) + 1
while(True):
    res=nextPrime(number)
    if res:
        print("The next number number is: ",number)
        break
    number += 1
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't know python but if it's anything like C then you are not assigning anything to your variables,  merely testing for equality.

```
while cnt1 == 1:
    nbr1 == nbr1 + 1
    if isPrime(lst2,nbr1):
        cnt1 == cnt1 + 1
```

Should become

```
while cnt1 == 1:
    nbr1 = nbr1 + 1             << changed here
    if isPrime(lst2,nbr1):
        cnt1 = cnt1 + 1          << and here
```

Comment: = (assignment) as opposed to == (test for equality)

Comment: I changed it to cnt = 0 instead of cnt1 = cnt1 + 1 but I see >>> 
13
>>>

Comment: There are 2 places where you are not assigning

Comment: Also I tried your method I see the same thing >>> 13 >>>

Comment: And if I change it to a composite number in function tester it gets back in a infinite loop.

Comment: `<< changed here` is a syntax error. Comments in Python begin with `#`, not `<<`.

Comment: Thanks although I wasn't trying for comments but just arrows to point to the line.

Answer (score 0):

Well this code help you

```
n=int(input())
p=n+1
while(p>n):
    c=0
    for i in range(2,p):
        if(p%i==0):
            break
        else:c+=1
    if(c>=p-2):
        print(p)
        break
    p+=1
```

Answer (score -1):

this code optimized for finding sudden next prime number of a given number.it takes about 6.750761032104492 seconds

```
def k(x):
   return pow(2,x-1,x)==1
n=int(input())+1
while(1):
    if k(n)==True:
        print(n)
        break
n=n+1
```

Comment: That is incorrect. pow(2, x-1, x) can be equal to 1 for composite numbers as well.